Observing pitch angle overshoots in my drone

For one of the flights I did with my 6kg quadcopter, i see sudden overshoots in Pitch angle as shown in image (see near time stamps "5:36:40" and "5:46:40"). The autopilot we use is built on PX4 and uses the cascaded PID controller. The pitch rate plot is also show at bottom which is a PID controller. The Integral term of the same is also shown in the middle. What can cause such sudden overshoots in pitch? I don't think it is a windup issue, because even though it looks like integrator saturated at 0.4, it sharply rose to that value only after overshoot started and integrator was attempting to correct it.
Is it due to some external disturbance or controller related issue wherein I need to tune some PID parameters.

When the feedback is on target, the integral contribution tends to be fairly charged while working close to its upper bound. That's not an ideal condition. The proportional doesn't deliver enough actuation as the input error is small.
Have you already tried to enlarge the saturation bounds (is it allowed?) or even remove them to perform some debugging?
Then, fine-tuning the PIDS gains will certainly help out.

Thank you for the reply!
I will try to increase the integral limit. This can prevent saturation and drive error to zero i think
